# Creating dynamic columns through dictionaries and then reducing DataFrame with fills

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a DataFrame something like:

```
  request                           data
0       a                   {'uid': 123}
1       a  {'type': 'POST', 'code': 200}
2       a                             {}
3       b                   {'uid': 456}
4       b   {'type': 'GET', 'code': 200}
5       b          {'args': 'some data'}
```

code to replicate:

```
data = [
            ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
            [{'uid': 123}, {'type': 'POST' ,'code':200}, {}, 
             {'uid': 456}, {'type': 'GET' ,'code':200}, {'args': 'some data'}]
        ]
cols = ['request', 'data']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(data[0], data[1]), columns=cols)
```

I want to create columns from the dicts in the data column and then flatten the table to be the minimum number of rows long it can be so my resultant DF would be:

```
  request  uid  type  code       args
0       a  123  POST   200       None
1       b  456   GET   200  some data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the dictionaries to dataframe with `apply(pd.Series)`, then aggregate using `groupby`+`first`:

```
df['data'].apply(pd.Series).groupby(df['request']).first()
```

output:

```
           uid  type   code       args
request                               
a        123.0  POST  200.0       None
b        456.0   GET  200.0  some data
```

Or using [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap):

```
from collections import ChainMap

(df.groupby('request')['data']
   .apply(lambda s: pd.Series(ChainMap(*s.values)))
   .unstack(level=1)
)
```